# How prove $|\xi_{1}v_{1}+\xi_{2}v_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}v_{n}|\le 1$

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces

**Question:**

> Let $n\ge 3\in N^{+}$ be  odd numbers, and $v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{n}$ be vectors in the plane with lengths equal to $1$. Prove that there exist  $\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\cdots,\xi_{n}\in\{-1,1\}$ such that
>   $$|\xi_{1}v_{1}+\xi_{2}v_{2}+\cdots+\xi_{n}v_{n}|\le 1$$

I find my problem very similar to this Romanian Mo 2001 problem 4: see:
[link](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2146775&sid=46e4cf11cdbe2b92e53b7648968bd0e5#p2146775)

**But my problem is hard, and I think is true.  Thank you for you help.**

Comment: Oh... you meant $\{-1,1\}$ instead of the interval $[-1,1]$ right? Good heavens, I read this so wrong. They are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ yes? And you saying "there exist" such $\xi$?

Comment: @NotNotLogical,Thank you I have edit.

Comment: If it is true for $n=3$, then you can apply the same reduction in your link. So it just needs proving for $n=3$ (and would then apply for $n\ge 3$, not just odd $n$).

Comment: The claim is definitely wrong for $n=4$: Let $v_1=(1,0), v_2=(\sqrt 2/2,\sqrt 2/2), v_3=(0,1), v_4=(-\sqrt 2/2,\sqrt 2/2)$. Then $\xi_1v_1+\xi_3v_3$ and $\xi_2v_2+\xi_4v_4$ are vectors of length $\sqrt 2$ on lines at an angle of $\pi/4$ and the best you can get is a length of $\sqrt{1+(\sqrt 2-1)^2} \approx 1.08$. - The claim is also clearly wrong for $n=4k+2$: Just take $2k+1$ vectors $(1,0)$ and $2k+1$ vectors $(0,1)$. The best you can get per direction is $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1$), resulting in a length of $\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 3):

I show below that the claim is true for $n=3$.

We can write $v_k=(\cos(\theta_k),\sin(\theta_k))$ with $\theta_k\in {\mathbb R}$,
for $k=1,2,3$. We may assume without loss that $\theta_1 < \theta_2 < \theta_3$ and
$\theta_3-\theta_1 \leq \pi$ (note that $v_k$ can be replaced with $-v_k$, in other words $\theta_k$ may be replaced with $\pi+\theta_k$). Then, the identity

$$
\big|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}+e^{i\theta_3}\big|^2=
1-4\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}\bigg)\Bigg(
\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}\bigg)-
\cos\bigg(\theta_2-\frac{\theta_1+\theta_3}{3}\bigg)
\Bigg)
$$

or, if you prefer (thanks to WimC for pointing this out),

$$
\big|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}+e^{i\theta_3}\big|^2=
1-8\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}\bigg)
\sin\bigg(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2}\bigg)
$$

shows that $\big|\big|v_1-v_2+v_3\big|\big| \leq 1$.

Comment: +1. Maybe a bit clearer in the form $$1-8 \sin\left(\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_2}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @WimC Point taken, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience I renumber the vectors $v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}$. Without loss of generality we can assume that all $\pm v_0, \dots, \pm v_{n-1}$ are different, $v_0 = (1,0)$ and all other $v_k$ have a strictly positive $y$-coordinate.  This situation will be considered below.

Let $n$ be odd and $0=\theta_0< \theta_1<\ldots<\theta_n=\pi$. Extend this sequence by taking $\theta_{-k} = \theta_{n-k}-\pi$ for $k\in\{1,\dots, n\}$. Let $$v_k = (\cos \theta_k, \sin \theta_k) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$ for $k\in\{-n,\ldots,n\}$ and$$v=v_0-v_1+v_2-\ldots+v_{n-1}.$$ I claim that $|v|\leq 1.$ Note that $|v|\leq 1$ if and only if $|\langle w, v\rangle|\leq 1$ for all $w$ on the unit circle. Let $k\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, $\alpha \in [\theta_k, \theta_{k+1})$ and $w = (\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$. Then $$\langle w, v_k \rangle > \langle w, v_{k-1} \rangle > \ldots > \langle w, v_{k-n+1} \rangle$$ and since $n$ is odd

$$(-1)^k\langle w, v \rangle = \langle w, v_k \rangle - \langle w, v_{k-1} \rangle + \ldots + \langle w, v_{k-n+1} \rangle$$

(alternating signs in the right hand side).  With the strict inequalities above it follows that

$$-1 \leq \langle w, v_{k-n+1} \rangle \leq (-1)^k\langle w, v \rangle \leq \langle w, v_k \rangle \leq 1$$ and so $|\langle \pm w, v \rangle| \leq 1$.  This proves the claim.

Comment: I am not so sure that "Without loss of generality we can assume that (…) all other $v_k$ have a strictly positive $y$-coordinate." What do you do, for example, when the four first vectors correspond to angles $0+10^{-6},\frac{\pi}{2}+10^{-7},\pi+10^{-8},\frac{3\pi}{2}+10^{-9} $ ?

Comment: I agree withe the @EwanDelanoy

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You can replace $v_k$ by $-v_k$ to make the $y$-coordinate positive if necessary for some $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.  In your specific example first add $-10^{-6}$ to all angles to make the first one $0$, then reduce $\bmod\,\pi$ to get the others in $(0,\pi)$ and reorder: $$0 <  \frac{\pi}{2}+10^{-9}-10^{-6} < \frac{\pi}{2}+10^{-7}-10^{-6}< \pi+10^{-8}-10^{-6}<\pi.$$ Basically this is the same normalization as implied in your own answer.